# How to I add small text under an image in HTML

Tags: html, css, tumblr

```html
<div class="pagenext">
  {block:pagination}{block:NextPage}
  <a href="{NextPage}">▶</a>
  {/block:NextPage}{/block:pagination}
</div>
```

my current code.
I'm changing the arrow to a cherry, I want it to be clear that you click it to get to the next page of my blog. What do I do?
I'd like it to say "Next" in small letters directly under it.

Comment: You should include your code in your questions. Otherwise is very hard for people to help you and they will down vote the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

This is not so hard. `<p>Hi my name is Peter click <a target="_blank" href="#">here</a>`  Now you can play with it in CSS.